# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_UserInfoRedux.UserInfoActions.userInfoRequest')

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm new to React Native, and I'm using Redux-Saga. Unfortunately, there is an error that I am unable to resolve.

I get this error when I dispatch an action:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_UserInfoRedux.UserInfoActions.userInfoRequest')

**Here's my Component wherein I dispatch the action:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {UserInfoActions } from '../Redux/UserInfoRedux'

class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
    username: '', password: '', rememberPwd:false
    }

    this.props.getUserInfo();

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.forceUpdate();
    if (newProps.userInfo.error === null && newProps.userInfo.payload !== null) {
      console.log(newProps.userInfo.payload.results);
    } else {
      console.log(">> error");
    }
  }

  render() {
  .
  .
  .
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userInfo: state.userInfo,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getUserInfo: () => {
      console.log('clicked');
      dispatch(UserInfoActions.userInfoRequest())
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,

  mapDispatchToProps
)(LoginScreen);
```

**Here's my redux class**

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  userInfoRequest: ['data'],
  userInfoSuccess: ['payload'],
  userInfoFailure: null
})

export const UserInfoTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  data: null,
  fetching: null,
  payload: null,
  error: null
})

/* ------------- Selectors ------------- */

export const UserInfoSelectors = {
  getData: state => state.data
}

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */

// request the data from an api
export const request = (state, { data }) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: true, data, payload: null })

// successful api lookup
export const success = (state, action) => {
  const { payload } = action
  return state.merge({ fetching: false, error: null, payload })
}

// Something went wrong somewhere.
export const failure = state =>
  state.merge({ fetching: false, error: true, payload: null })

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.USER_INFO_REQUEST]: request,
  [Types.USER_INFO_SUCCESS]: success,
  [Types.USER_INFO_FAILURE]: failure
})
```

**And finally my Saga class**

```
/* ***********************************************************
* A short word on how to use this automagically generated file.
* We're often asked in the ignite gitter channel how to connect
* to a to a third party api, so we thought we'd demonstrate - but
* you should know you can use sagas for other flow control too.
*
* Other points:
*  - You'll need to add this saga to sagas/index.js
*  - This template uses the api declared in sagas/index.js, so
*    you'll need to define a constant in that file.
*************************************************************/

import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {UserInfoActions} from '../Redux/UserInfoRedux'

export function * getUserInfo (api, action) {
  const { data } = action
  // get current data from Store
  // const currentData = yield select(UserInfoSelectors.getData)
  // make the call to the api
  const response = yield call(api.getUserInfo, data)

  // success?
  if (response.ok) {
    // You might need to change the response here - do this with a 'transform',
    // located in ../Transforms/. Otherwise, just pass the data back from the api.
    yield put(UserInfoActions.userInfoSuccess(response.data))
  } else {
    yield put(UserInfoActions.userInfoFailure())
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my own stupid mistake! Didn't know the importance of {} when importing. Removed {} in one of my imports and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was assigning a variable to a hook call, but I didn't return anything inside that hook call, so my variable would not receive any value, hence the `undefined` value.

It is simple: if you are receiving `undefined` value, then this means your variable has no value, which is not what you may expect.

Try to debug your code to see where the error is coming from and why it is not giving the desired output.

**Remember:** `undefined` means no value.